# How do I implement a UIImagePickerController with a TabBarController

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller

I have been beating my head on this for a few hours. I have some sample code (using a `UINavigationController`) when the view loads the camera roll will be presented.  However, when I try to incorporate the same code into my app, which has a `tabBarController`, I get a blank modal `UIImagePickerController`. I didn't track down what I am doing wrong.

```
// bring up image picker
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) {

    NSLog(@"UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary available");

    UIImagePickerController *ipc  = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    ipc.delegate      = self;
    ipc.sourceType    = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
    ipc.allowsEditing = YES;

    [self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:ipc animated:YES];
    [ipc release];
}
```

Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: Did your sample have this code in `viewDidLoad` ? And was it calling `presentModalViewController:animated:` on its navigation controller, or on itself? (And you know that the sample code works?)

Comment: The root controller will call presentModalViewController:animated: and when the modal view's viewDidLoad method had the above logic.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what has changed, but this is possible by calling `presentViewController` from your tabBarController. This is the standard now and ensures your camera or image picker always gets presented as a full screen modal view.

For reference: [presentViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)